# Restart the Uart3 In Pic32MX795F512L

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic32

I am using a PIC32MX795F512L controller for my project. I need to restart the UART3 module using 32-bit peripheral library code. I am able to restart UART1 and UART2 successfully using the following code.

```c
    CloseUART1();
    Idle_Timeout(1);
    UARTConfigure(UART1, UART_ENABLE_PINS_TX_RX_ONLY);
    UARTSetFifoMode(UART1, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);
    UARTSetLineControl(UART1, UART_DATA_SIZE_8_BITS | UART_STOP_BITS_1 | UART_PARITY_NONE);
    UARTSetDataRate(UART1, GetPeripheralClock(), 115200);
    UARTEnable(UART1, UART_ENABLE_FLAGS(UART_PERIPHERAL | UART_RX | UART_TX));
    INTEnable(INT_SOURCE_UART_RX(UART1), INT_ENABLED);
    INTSetVectorPriority(INT_VECTOR_UART(UART1), INT_PRIORITY_LEVEL_1);
    INTSetVectorSubPriority(INT_VECTOR_UART(UART1), INT_SUB_PRIORITY_LEVEL_1);
    Idle_Timeout(1);
```

In above code `CloseUART1();` function turns off the UART1 module. But when I use the same function for UART3 it gives "Undefined reference error".

```c
    CloseUART3();
    UARTConfigure(UART3, UART_ENABLE_PINS_TX_RX_ONLY);
    UARTSetFifoMode(UART3, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);
    UARTSetLineControl(UART3, UART_DATA_SIZE_8_BITS | UART_STOP_BITS_1 | UART_PARITY_NONE);
    UARTSetDataRate(UART3, GetPeripheralClock(), 9600);
    UARTEnable(UART3, UART_ENABLE_FLAGS(UART_PERIPHERAL | UART_RX | UART_TX));
    INTEnable(INT_SOURCE_UART_RX(UART3), INT_ENABLED);
    INTSetVectorPriority(INT_VECTOR_UART(UART3), INT_PRIORITY_LEVEL_3);
    INTSetVectorSubPriority(INT_VECTOR_UART(UART3), INT_SUB_PRIORITY_LEVEL_1);
```

Please guide me to turn off the UART3 module and restart the module using 32-bit peripheral library code.

Comment: Apparently there is only `CloseUART1()` but not `CloseUART3()`. Is this former function part of the library, whose documentation you don't link? If not, where is it declared and where is it defined?

Comment: Yes You are right but there are some functions to disable the Uart and clear all flags i don't know those functions

Comment: My aim is to turn off the Uart module and again turn on the uart module

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a link to the library's documentation.

Comment: There isn't a CloseUART3() function.  You need to write your own, basically refer to the Datasheet and see which Peripheral bits need to be set/unset to reset the Port, look for U3MODE in the register list as a starting point...